# How typescript is converted to javascript in angular2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am learning angular2 with typescript.Its quite fascinating to work but I am facing trouble understanding the actual working of any application as the code we have written will be in typescript.but the code to be executed is always in ECMAScript.

I have heard about transpiler but couldnt understand more about it.

I was just wondering how this functionality has been achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

- **Transpiling on the fly** (like how it's done in plunkr):

  ```
  <script>
    System.config({
      transpiler: 'typescript', 
      typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
      packages: {
        'app': {
          defaultExtension: 'ts'
        }
      } 
    });
    (...)
  </script>
  ```

  Here is a sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/aG4TdHbAls3cu04AAt64
- **Preprocess TypeScript files** using the typeScript compiler. Then you only rely on compiled JavaScript files. Such approach is described in the 5min quickstart on angular.io: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart.